# Exporting blender project in gltf with multiple animations

Tags: animation, export, gltf, nla-editor, actions

I have create a simple box opening and close animation in my blender project using the NLA editor, I need to export this project to  gltf format in order to convert later on the file using Reality Converter to obtain USDZ file (with the animations open and close stored).

I can't understand why in blender the animation sequance is perfect, the box open and then close, but , when I export in gltf and open it on Reality Converter I only see the open animation.

How can I export the multiple animation in order later on convert it in USDZ format.

I need a final usdz file with multiple animations stored (so I can activate the animation by code (AR Project) )

I attach a screenshot of my current working animation in blender.

[image: bl1]

[image: bl2]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the glTF exporter exports separate NLA tracks as separate glTF named animations. If multiple tracks have the same name, they will all be exported as part of the same glTF named animation.

I suspect that your glTF file has four named animations in it: `CloseAnimation`, `OpenAnimation`, `ClosePlaneAnimation`, and `OpenPlaneAnimation`. I further suspect that in Reality Converter you are only playing one of these animations (perhaps "OpenAnimation"). This is why you are only seeing it open.

If you want the box to open and then close as a single animation, you should either merge your strips into the same track, or rename your tracks to have the same name.

If (as I suspect) you want one glTF animation with the box opening, and a second with the box closing, you should rename the `ClosePlaneAnimation` track to `CloseAnimation` (matching the name of the first track) and rename the `OpenPlaneAnimation` track to `OpenAnimation`. That should give you two named animations in the glTF file that you can procedurally trigger.